# Flutter pop cupertino onpressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So when I klik on the 'Delete' cupertino, a pop up reminder shows. What I want is when the pop up shows, the cupertino auto close.

Here is my code:

```
onLongPress: () {
        showCupertinoModalPopup(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
              actions: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Delete Chat'),
                            content: const Text('Messages will be removed from this device only.'),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                                child: const Text('Cancel'),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                                child: const Text('Ok'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                      // Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Delete',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
        );
      },
```

Tried adding the Navigator.pop(context); but then the pop up won't show when I click on the cupertino. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Try change context of alert dialog like

```
onLongPress: () {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (alertContext) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('Delete Chat'),
                        content: const Text('Messages will be removed from this device only.'),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(alertContext, 'Cancel'),
                            child: const Text('Cancel'),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(alertContext, 'Cancel'),
                            child: const Text('Ok'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                  // Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Delete',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  },
```